# interpreting make MingW error windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I'm looking for a push in the right direction. I am trying to compile the c++ code from this repo https://github.com/yujiali/pygco.

I am running make (g++) from within git bash.

Make all ran perfectly.

```
$ make all
g++ -fPIC \
    -c gco_source/LinkedBlockList.cpp \
    -o gco_source/LinkedBlockList.o
gco_source/LinkedBlockList.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
g++ -fPIC \
    -c gco_source/graph.cpp \
    -o gco_source/graph.o
gco_source/graph.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
g++ -fPIC \
    -c gco_source/maxflow.cpp \
    -o gco_source/maxflow.o
gco_source/maxflow.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
g++ -fPIC \
    -c gco_source/GCoptimization.cpp \
    -o gco_source/GCoptimization.o
gco_source/GCoptimization.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
gco_source/GCoptimization.cpp:18:0: warning: "NOMINMAX" redefined [enabled by default]
c:\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/os_defines.h:46:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
gco_source/GCoptimization.cpp:21:23: warning: 'GCO_CLOCKS_PER_SEC' initialized and declared 'extern' [enabled by default]
g++ -fPIC \
    -c cgco.cpp \
    -o cgco.o
cgco.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
g++ -shared -fPIC \
    gco_source/LinkedBlockList.o \
    gco_source/graph.o \
    gco_source/maxflow.o \
    gco_source/GCoptimization.o \
    cgco.o \
    -o libcgco.so
```

looking good so far

[image]

```
$ make test_wrapper
g++ -L. test_wrapper.cpp \
    -o test_wrapper -lcgco
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcgco
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_wrapper] Error 1
```

Any guesses on what the -lcgco flag means here? Is this a windows error, a make error, and MingW error, or specific to the code i'm compiling?

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: This means "**l**ink with lib**cgco**"

Comment: This is a linker error. `-lcgco` means link in libcgco.so, which we can see in the directory list so clearly it exists. `-L.` should have the linker looking in the current folder, and I'm not familiar with the tools you're using so I'm bailing before I say anything stupid.

Comment: You can't use `.so` files in Windows. `g++ -shared` in mingw will produce a DLL, but you can't link directly against a DLL; you would need to also generate an export library and link against that. But DLLs and SOs have other differences too. [Docs](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll).  Maybe your better option would just be to make a static library instead of a shared object